# In how many ways can $kn$ people be arranged around $k$ tables such that each table has $n$ people?

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

Find a general formula to arrange $kn$ people around $k$ tables such that each table has $n$ people?

The way I dealt with it was to form $k$ groups of $n$ and got ans as (kn)!/(n!)^k which is wrong please tell the mistake

Comment: the # of ways of arranging $n$ people around a **round** table is $(n-1)!.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here’s a slightly different approach to counting the arrangements.

Imagine that we line up the $kn$ people at the door and let them into the room one at a time. The first $n$ of them are seated in order clockwise around the first table, the second $n$ in order clockwise around the second table, and so on. There are $(kn)!$ ways to line them up, so there are $(kn)!$ different possible seatings if both the tables and the seats at each table are considered distinct (e.g., if the tables and the seats at each table are numbered).

However, the default assumption is that two arrangements of people around a table are considered the same if one is a rotation of the other. Thus, when the first $n$ people take their seats around the first table, it doesn’t matter where the first person sits, as long as the others fill the remaining seats in order clockwise around the table. Thus, what we originally counted as $n$ distinct arrangements, one for each place at which the first person could sit, is really only one. The same is true for each of the $k$ tables, so we need to divide the original answer of $(kn)!$ by $n^k$, a factor of $n$ for each table. If this is the intended interpretation, there are $\frac{(kn)!}{n^k}$ arrangements.

Finally, if the individual tables are not considered distinct, we must divide by $k!$, and there are only $\frac{(kn)!}{k!n^k}$.

Answer (score 3):

The first part of your proposed solution is to count the number of distinct ways to partition $kn$ people into $k$ groups of $n$ people.  This is done by multinomial coefficient:  there are $$\binom{kn}{n,n,\ldots,n} = \frac{(kn)!}{(n!)^k}$$ such ways.  To see why, think of the people as being labeled $1, 2, \ldots, kn$.  For each person, we assign a table numbered $1, \ldots, k$ in the following manner:  first, we select $\binom{kn}{n}$ people for the first table.  Then out of the remaining $(k-1)n$ people, we select $\binom{(k-1)n}{n}$ people for the second table; and so on until the final table has only $\binom{n}{n}$ possible choices.  Thus the total number of arrangements is $$\binom{kn}{n}\binom{(k-1)n}{n} \cdots \binom{n}{n} = \prod_{i=1}^k \binom{in}{n} = \prod_{i=1}^k \frac{(in)!}{n!((i-1)n)!} = \frac{1}{(n!)^k} \prod_{i=1}^k \frac{(in)!}{((i-1)n)!} = \frac{(kn)!}{(n!)^k}.$$

The second part of the solution is to then consider the number of distinct circular permutations of $n$ people around a table.  An arrangement is considered equivalent to another arrangement if they are invariant with respect to a rotation of the table.  So the way to do this is to fix one person's position at the table and count the number of ways to arrange the others relative to that person; i.e., there are $(n-1)!$ circular permutations of $n$ people.  Since there are $k$ tables, for each partition of the whole group into tables, there are $((n-1)!)^k$ ways to seat them.  So the total number of seating arrangements is $$((n-1)!)^k \frac{(kn)!}{(n!)^k} = \frac{(kn)!}{n^k}.$$

Comment: Thank you sir

Comment: @Ken If you found the answer useful, you should accept it and upvote it, rather than simply commenting.

Comment: It is unclear if the tables are considered indistinguishable, but if they are then you have to divide this answer by $k!$.